# Adding application to Windows 7 list of autoplay handlers

Tags: windows, windows-7, registry, autoplay

I am developing a lightweight WPF application that will take multimedia files from either the local file system or removable media devices and upload them to Amazon S3 cloud storage.  One of the project requirements is for Windows 7 to recognize when a device (e.g., camera, SD card, etc.) is detected and make my application one of the AutoPlay options.

We are NOT requiring the uploader application to AutoRun without user interaction.  I simply want to get my application added to the list of avalable AutoPlay event handlers.

I'm aware that a number of registry keys must be added to the HKLM hive in the Windows registry.  My research seems to indicate that this is not possible with ClickOnce installation (which is the install method desired for this project), but my information is a couple of years old.

Is is still the case that a full-blown Windows Installer is required to make this a reality?  Or is there some method of achieving the desired result with a ClickOnce WPF install?